# How to handle JSON data?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Ok, so I have a data from JSON. The structure of this data looks like this:

[image]

As you can see this data contains an array with name, type and value. What I need to do is to convert is somehow to use this function:

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google.visualization.arraytodatatable

This function need the data to be given in this format:

```
['Country', 'Population', 'Area'],
['CN', 1324, 9640821],
['IN', 1133, 3287263],
['US', 304, 9629091],
['ID', 232, 1904569],
['BR', 187, 8514877]
```

So in my case would be:

```
[name, type, value]
data iself
```

Any help?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show your workings. Also it looks like you have an array containing a number of arrays with each one containing a single object. That might help you get started.

Comment: where is the json coming from?

Comment: @Andy I had no idea what syntax to use to get the value. I've tried couple of test but none of them worked and that's why I didn't appended any code. I know this looks much amateurishly but I didn't know how to explain it better. Anyway, guys beneath has provided exact solution with map method which is really what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
var result = data.map(function(item){
    var i = item[0];
    return [i.name, i.type, i.value];
}); // Map the data from objects to the require arrays.
result.unshift(['Country', 'Population', 'Area']); // Add the description row.
```

This first maps all the data in the source data to `[name, type, value]` items, in the `result` array, then adds the "description" array to the front of the result.

Comment: Thank you, I had no idea about map method. This is exacly what I was looking for. Sorry for such a bad description of my problem, but I didn't know how to explain it better. Your answer is as good as @pawel

Answer (score 1):

You can convert an array of items to an array of modified items using `Array.prototype.map`.

In you example this could be something along these lines.

```
var flattened = object.data.map( function( item ){
      return [ item[0].name, item[0].type, item[0].value ];
});
```

Comment: thank you very much, it covers all I needed, your answer is as good as @Cerbrus

Comment: yeah, we've posted very similar answers just seconds apart :)

Answer (score 1):

here you go. lazy programmer service.

```
// obj is your original json
var newdata = [];
for(var i=0;i<obj.data.length;i++)
  newdata.push([obj.data[i][0].name,obj.data[i][0].type,obj.data[i][0].value]);
newdata.unshift(['Country', 'Population', 'Area']);
```

Comment: different approach with the loop but still as good as the others, thank you @Jabran Saeed